# AWS lambda function failing in Amazon Connect

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I have written an AWS lambda function in node.js to send an email, which is invoked in an Amazon Connect contact flow.  In the error branch it plays a prompt saying "lambda function failed."  I verified the IAM role has permission to send email with SES, the sender/receiver emails are verified in SES, and also the lambda function has permissions for Amazon Connect.

The email does actually get sent out, but oddly I still hear the prompt "lambda function failed."  Here is the code:

```
"use strict";

const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const sender = "Sender Name <sender@email.com>";
const recipient = "recipient@email.com";
const subject = "ALERT:  no agents are logged in";
const body_text = "There are no agents logged in";

const body_html = 
`<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>ALERT</h1>
  <p>Ther are no agents logged in to take calls in the queue.</p>
</body>
</html>`;

const charset = "UTF-8";

let params = { 
  Source: sender, 
  Destination: { 
    ToAddresses: [
      recipient 
    ],
  },
  Message: {
    Subject: {
      Data: subject,
      Charset: charset
    },
    Body: {
      Text: {
        Data: body_text,
        Charset: charset 
      },
      Html: {
        Data: body_html,
        Charset: charset
      }
    }
  },
};

const ses = new aws.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'});


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  ses.sendEmail(params, function(err, data) {

    if(err) {
      console.log("fail");
      callback(err, err.message);
    } 
    else {
      console.log("success");
      callback(null);
    }
  });
};
```

I checked the cloudwatch logs and don't see any error:

```
00:17:24
START RequestId: 17f1e239-990e-11e8-96bb-a1980f44db91 Version: $LATEST
00:17:24
2018-08-06T00:17:24.723Z 17f1e239-990e-11e8-96bb-a1980f44db91 success
00:17:24
END RequestId: 17f1e239-990e-11e8-96bb-a1980f44db91
00:17:24
REPORT RequestId: 17f1e239-990e-11e8-96bb-a1980f44db91 Duration: 226.51 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB
```

How do I troubleshoot this?

EDIT:

I enabled contact flow logs.  In CloudWatch I noticed this:

```
{ 
"Parameters": { "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:769182588423:function:noAgentEmail", "TimeLimit": "8000" }, 
"Timestamp": "2018-08-06T06:36:31.786Z", 
"ContactFlowModuleType": "InvokeExternalResource", 
"Results": "The Lambda Function Returned An Error.", 
"ExternalResults": { "forceClose": "false" }, 
"ContactId": "458027b0-d895-439e-bc06-114500dce64a", 
"ContactFlowId": "arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:769182588423:instance/1e2ddedd-8335-42fe-89de-1e986fc016ef/contact-flow/2329af39-682c-4dc8-b3a2-5e7fe64de5d2" 
}
```

What's confusing is it indicates the lambda function returned something:

```
 "ExternalResults": { "forceClose": "false" }
```

But this is clearly not the case given the code.  What's going on?

Comment: Where do you see the prompt `"lambda function failed."`?

Comment: This is a node configured in the contact flow, in the error branch.  Here is a screenshot:  https://imgur.com/a/AU5Sjth

Comment: Do you need `callback(null, {});` perhaps?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that worked!  Please answer below so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things to ensure your working Lambda function can be used for Connect.

As mentioned in the above answer, the return value should be a flat JSON object. As the guide says:

> Nested and complex objects are not supported.

So, it should look something like this when you execute the lambda directly:

```
Response:
{
  "statusPop": "success",
  "id": "1",
  "name": "me",
}
```

The property names and values need to be

> alphanumeric, dash, and underscore characters.

Oh, and here's what tripped me up: 
  Amazon Connect sends paramters as part of a hierarchical structure, so any parameters you're expecting need to be referenced as

```
event['Details']['Parameters']['statusPop'];
```

instead of

```
event['statusPop'];
```

And don't forget to add permissions using:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name function:my-lambda-function --statement-id 1 \ 
 --principal connect.amazonaws.com --action lambda:InvokeFunction --source-account 123456789012 \ 
 --source-arn arn:aws:connect:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/def1a4fc-ac9d-11e6-b582-06a0be38cccf
```

More info and in depth details of what I mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda needs to return a flat filed JSON object. It looks like on success your lambda callbacks with null.

Update your exports to this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  ses.sendEmail(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("fail");
      //callback(err, err.message);
      callback(null, {"status":"error"});
    } 
    else {
      console.log("success");
      callback(null, {"status":"success"});
    }
  });
});
```

More information on lambda/connect requirements here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html

Note:

> The output returned from the function must be a flat object of key/value pairs, with values that include only alphanumeric, dash, and underscore characters. Nested and complex objects are not supported. The size of the returned data must be less than 32 Kb of UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 0):

you must return a valid JSON object such as below example

```
export const handler = async(event) => {

console.log("event" + JSON.stringify(event));

let amount = event['Details']['Parameters']['amount'];
console.log("amount:" + amount);

let resultMap = {
        "amountValid": "valid"
    };

console.log("resultMap" + JSON.stringify(resultMap));
return resultMap;
```

};